# importing mortality rates

Tags: fitting

In[1]=dataFrance = Import["G:\french female death rates.xlsx"]

Out[1]={{{""}, {""}, {""}, {""}, {""}, {""}, {""}, {""}, {""}, {""}, {"0     \
0.003531      "}, {"1     0.000312     "}, {"2     0.000191    "}, \
{"3     0.000151      "}, {"4     0.000121    "}, {"5     0.000103    \
  "}, {"6     0.000099      "}, {"7     0.000081      "}, {"8     \
0.000087 "}, {"9     0.000087 "}, {"10     0.000086 "}, {"11     \
0.000083 "}, {"12     0.000099"}, {"13     0.000108"}, {"14     \
0.000131 "}, {"15     0.000155 "}, {"16     0.000195 "}, {"17     \
0.000221"}, {"18     0.000275"}, {"19     0.000286"}, {"21     \
0.000299    "}, {"22     0.000281"}, {"23     0.000289     "}, {"24   \
  0.000290   "}, {"25     0.000300 "}, {"26     0.000317"}, {"27     \
0.000329     "}, {"28     0.000335 "}, {"29     0.000351  "}, {"30    \
 0.000389   "}, {"31     0.000411    "}, {"32     0.000464     "}, \
{"33     0.000508   "}, {"34     0.000559"}, {"35     0.000633   "}, \
{"36     0.000665     "}, {"37     0.000743"}, {"38     0.000842  "}, \
{"39     0.000946  "}, {"40     0.001010   "}, {"41     0.001125"}, \
{"42     0.001244 "}, {"43     0.001384   "}, {"44     0.001501 "}, \
{"45     0.001667 "}, {"46     0.001798 "}, {"47     0.001970 "}, \
{"48     0.002130  "}, {"49     0.002310  "}, {"51     0.002634 "}, \
{"52     0.002810"}, {"53     0.002980"}, {"54     0.003134   "}, \
{"55     0.003367  "}, {"56     0.003543  "}, {"57     0.003830  "}, \
{"58     0.003986 "}, {"59     0.004260 "}, {"60     0.004541 "}, \
{"61     0.004838 "}, {"62     0.005299  "}, {"63     0.005632   "}, \
{"64     0.006059 "}, {"65     0.006538    "}, {"66     0.007077  "}, \
{"67     0.007695   "}, {"68     0.008479    "}, {"69     0.009384  \
"}, {"70     0.010360   "}, {" 71     0.011452  "}, {"72     0.012751 \
  "}, {"73     0.014154   "}, {"74     0.015989   "}, {"75     \
0.017850   "}, {"76     0.020433  "}, {"77     0.022878   "}, {"78    \
 0.026255   "}, {"79     0.030208"}, {"80     0.034888  "}, {"81     \
0.040181"}, {"82     0.046019 "}, {"83     0.052873 "}, {"84     \
0.060357"}, {"85     0.070242"}, {"86     0.080493"}, {"87     \
0.093503 "}, {"88     0.107465"}, {"89     0.123421 "}, {"90     \
0.139276"}, {"91     0.158692"}, {"92     0.178581 "}, {"93     \
0.200949 "}, {"94     0.223490"}, {"95     0.247762 "}, {"96     \
0.274692 "}, {"97     0.300969 "}, {"98     0.331739"}, {"99     \
0.357650"}, {"100     0.388528"}, {"101     0.426836"}, {"102     \
0.462185"}, {"103     0.496883"}, {"104     0.503713"}, {"105     \
0.534220"}, {"106     0.602750"}, {"107     0.616000"}, {"108     \
0.656071   "}, {"109     0.707503 "}, {"110+    0.800964"}}}

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, 
  b Exp[m x]/(1 + b Exp[m x]), {{b, 0}, {m, -1}}, x]

NonlinearModelFit::fitd: First argument data in NonlinearModelFit is not a list or a rectangular array. >>

I am importing data from an excel file .
How i do fix this ? please?

Comment: replace `data` by `ToExpression[First[data]]` or shouldn't it be `ToExpression[First[dataFrance]]`

Answer (score 2):

The import has imported the single sheet in the "xlsx" file.In the following `data` was the copied and pasted information in the question (deleting `\`). It can be used for data analysis and  visualization after some processing:

```
datm1 = data[[1,11 ;;]];(* take first sheet and remove leading empty cells*)
datm2 = StringSplit[#] & @@@ datm;(*split string at white space*)
datm3 = Map[ToExpression,Map[StringReplace[#, "+" -> ""] &,datm2, {2}], {2}];      
(*deal with '+' sign at 110 then convert to expression*)
```

The above was done from data provided in the question.

It can now be manipulated,e.g.

```
ListPlot[datm3, Frame -> True,FrameLabel -> {"Age", "Female Death Rate"}]
```

[image]

**Comment**

Numerical data is usually imported well. 
This datafile  was imported as strings. I am uncertain how the file was made. The'+' would have been problematic for the first column.

Comment: thank you for your reply                                                         dataFrance = Import["G:\\french female death rates.xlsx"]
datm1 = data[[1, 11 ;;]];
datm2 = StringSplit[#] & @@@ datm;
datm3 = Map[ToExpression, Map[StringReplace[#, "+" -> ""] &,datm2, {2}], {2}];  
   is what you told me to do ? am getting same output , why so ?